# Setting size of custom edit form for Kendo UI grid with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a custom edit form for my Kendo UI grid, but I need to make it wider to fit my layout.  The way I currently do it works, except for that the position of the Update and Cancel button does not get adjusted (= they wind up in the middle instead of to the right).

Here is how I adjust the size (by specify this in the edit field of the grid options):

```
edit: function (e) {
  var popupWindow = e.container.getKendoWindow();
  popupWindow.setOptions({
  width: 640
  });
```

}

Here is a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bRaFZFjrzR3IyeVrmulR

**What is the best way to set the width of the edit form so that the buttons, etc. also get positioned correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting the width of k-edit-form-container to auto:

```
edit: function (e) {
  var popupWindow = e.container.getKendoWindow();
  e.container.find(".k-edit-form-container").width("auto");
  popupWindow.setOptions({
  width: 640
});
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bRaFZFjrzR3IyeVrmulR

I found solution here: http://dojo.telerik.com/aVOj